# Marginal distributions

Tags: probability

I'm given the following problem:

Determine the marginal density functions $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ and the marginal distribution functions $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(y)$ of the following joint probability density functions:

a) $f(x,y)=4xy,\;\;\;x>0$ and $y<1$.

b) $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{8}(x^2-y^2)e^{-x},\;\;\;0<x<\infty$ and $|y|<x.$

---

For a) I don't see the logic of the problem because the region where $f$ is defined is $\{(x,y):x>0 \;\wedge\;y<1 \}$. To find the marginal function of $X$ then we integrate over the whole domain of $y$ which would yield:

$$\int^1_{-\infty}4xy\, dy = 2xy^2\Big|^{y=1}_{y=-\infty}$$

Am I wrong?

For b) I computed the marginal function for $Y$ which was
$$f_Y(y)=\int_{x}f(x,y)\,dx = \frac{y^2}{8};\;\;\;-x<y<x.$$

Now, how do I compute the marginal distribution of $Y$? By definition:

$$F_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^yf_Y(y)\,dy.$$
In this case the limits of integration would be from $-x$ to $y<x$. But this seems odd because we would write $F_Y(y)$ in terms of $x$.

Am I doing something wrong? I appreciate your help.

Comment: In a) we need a correct description of the places where the density is non-zero. Maybe it is supposed to be $0\lt x\lt 1$, $0\lt y\lt 1$.

Comment: Possibly the question is wrong there.

Comment: For (b) note that $0<x<\infty, |y|<x$ is equivalent to $-\infty < y <\infty, x > |y|$

Comment: @GrahamKemp But that integral wouldn't make sense since the integrand is $\dfrac{y^2}{8}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the support for $f(x,y)$ in (b) can be equivalently expressed as:

- $x\in [0, \infty), y\in(-x,x)$
- $y\in (-\infty, \infty), x\in (|y|, \infty)$

So thus:

$$\begin{align}
f(x,y) & = \frac 1 {8} (x^2-y^2)e^{-x} \quad : y\in (-\infty, \infty), x\in (|y|, \infty)
\\[2ex]
f_Y(y) & = \int_{|y|}^\infty f(s, y)\operatorname d s \quad : y\in(-\infty, \infty)
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac 1 8 \int_{|y|}^{\infty} (s^2 - y^2) e^{-s}\operatorname d s
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac 1 8 (|y|^2+2|y|+2-y^2)e^{-|y|}
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac 1 4 (|y|+1)e^{-|y|}
\\[2ex]
 F_Y(y) & = \int_{-\infty}^y f_Y(t)\operatorname d t \quad : y\in(-\infty, \infty)
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac 1 4 \int_{-\infty}^y (|t|+1)e^{-|t|} \operatorname d t
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac 1 4 \begin{cases}
 \int_{-\infty}^y (-t+1)e^{t} \operatorname d t & : y\leq 0
 \\[1ex]
 \int_{-\infty}^0 (-t+1)e^{t} \operatorname d t + \int_{0}^y (t+1)e^{-t} \operatorname d t & : y> 0
\end{cases}
\\[1ex] & \ddots
\end{align}$$

Can you complete from here?

Likewise

$$\begin{align}
f(x,y) & = \frac{1}{8}(x^2-y^2)e^{-x},\quad : x\in [0,\infty), y\in(-x,x)
\\[2ex]
f_X(x) & = \int_{-x}^x f(x, t)\operatorname d t \quad : x\in[0,\infty)
\\[2ex]
 F_X(x) & = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(s)\operatorname d s \quad : x\in[0,\infty)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks. My problem was finding the limits of integration: to be clear, when I solve for the marginal of let's say $X$ I compute the integral with respect to $Y$ and therefore, given the conditions where the joint pdf is not $0$, I look for $y$ restricted by $x$ (even if the conditions look as though $x$ is restricted by $y$). When I find these restrictions for $y$, then I integrate. Right?